# Validate strings if null or empty

Tags: c#, validation, null

I would like to check a variable beforehand to see whether it is empty or null. If it is null or empty, it should take a character string defined by me.  My code:

```
public string Ergebnis { get; set; }
public string Stufe { get; set; }
public string Niveau { get; set; }
public string Note { get; set; }
public DateTime? Datum { get; set; }
```

And the function:

```
public void EndEdit()
        {

            var newdate = Convert.ToDateTime(Datum).ToShortDateString();
            var client = new RestClient("MYDOMAIN");
            var request = new RestRequest("SOME THINGS", Method.POST)
                .AddUrlSegment("name", Name)
                .AddUrlSegment("kompetenzID", KompetenzID)
                .AddUrlSegment("ergebnis", Ergebnis)
                .AddUrlSegment("stufe", Stufe)
                .AddUrlSegment("niveau", Niveau)
                .AddUrlSegment("note", Note)
                .AddUrlSegment("datum", newdate)
                .AddUrlSegment("kuerzel", Kuerzel)
                .AddUrlSegment("background", Background)
                .AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + ViewFingerPrint);

            IRestResponse restResponse = client.Execute(request);

            if (restResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Der SuS ist nicht in der Datenbank vorhanden.");
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
```

I thought I could do it with an if statement. However, my function then does not recognize the variable. My code:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Ergebnis))
            {
                string Ergenisneu = "-";
            } else
            {
                string Ergebnisneu = Ergebnis;
            }
```

If I insert the result here:

.AddUrlSegment("ergebnis", Ergebnis)

It does not recognize the variable and says: The variable is never used. How else can I tell the variable that it has a string at null?

The same thing happens in this variant:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (Ergebnis))
                 string Ergebnis= "-";
```

Comment: You are declaring a new variable in a nested scope. Drop the `string` in front of the variable inside the `if` statement to use the already existing `Ergebnis` property.

Comment: `Ergebnis = string.IsNullOrEmpty (Ergebnis) ? "-" :  Ergebnis;`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are redeclaring the variable `Ergebnis` inside the if statement, which you should not do, because it is then creating another variable with the same name in a different scope. Then what happens is you are assigning a value to that new variable, but it never gets used. Here's what you should do instead:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Ergebnis))
{
    Ergebnis = "-";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this. you are declaring string inside if and else. declare above if condition and reassign value.

```
string Ergenisneu = string.Empty;

Ergenisneu = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Ergebnis) ? "-":Ergebnis
```